# Does Google Cloud Functions support multiple functions in a single deployment package?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

Moreover, what's an efficient way to deploy a GCF solution given the requirement for multiple related functions? (And given that each deployment step is fairly slow - 10's of seconds)

This sounds like a straightforward question, but I can't find a straight answer with exactly what to do. I've read a few related answers on SO, but they aren't very clear.

The Google documentation here mentions exporting "one or more functions": https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/

But when it comes time to deploy, the CLI command explicitly only deploys one function as far as I can tell: `gcloud beta functions deploy OneFunctionNameHere`.

What am I missing?
If I have several related functions in one index.js, surely I don't need several slow `gcloud beta functions deploy` commands?
(Or maybe I do so that I get independent reporting for each one???)

I'm guessing one of these might be the answer, but I'm really not sure:

1. Push/deploy once from local source into a GCP bucket, then deploy from that bucket for the other functions? (Faster?)
2. Extend the access URL like ".../MyFunction/SomeSubFunction" and use request.params to route to the right response-generating code. (There are npm packages for that..)
3. Run multiple deploys in *parallel* so that 'time to deploy' isn't a big issue (bandwidth allowing...)

Thanks for any wisdom for a better solution.

Comment: Could you find a solution to this?

Comment: @SamikR - Nope. I think the only solution (The standard solution?) is to extend the URL as I mentioned in my point 2. It's a few lines of code to inspect request.params and then use a switch/if-then to chain to the required function. There are even some npm packages to help I recall, but rolling your own is easy enough.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not think it is possible to deploy multiple functions using one command for google cloud - as mentioned by various posts. To make things easy, I ended up using the following command:

```
sed -n 's/exports\.\([a-zA-Z0-9\-_#]*\).*/\1/p' index.js | xargs -I {} gcloud beta functions deploy {} --trigger-http
```

Be careful when using this, specifically, make sure that the output of `sed -n 's/exports\.\([a-zA-Z0-9\-_#]*\).*/\1/p' index.js` are only the name of the functions you want to export.

Comment: Add a `-P` to `xargs` to make it run them in parallel. My version: 

`"deploy:all": "sed -n 's/exports\\.\\([a-zA-Z0-9\\-_#]*\\).*/\\1/p' index.js | xargs -I {} -n 1 -P 5 yarn deploy {}",`

Answer (score 4):

You can have multiple **Firebase Cloud Functions** in one deployment or single index.js file.

index.js

```
 const functions = require('firebase-functions')
 const admin = require('firebase-admin')
 admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase)

 exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
     res.end()
 })

 exports.saveToken = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {
     res.end()
 })
```

Call the functions with a POST request

https://us-central1-projectname.cloudfunctions.net/saveToken

and

https://us-central1-projectname.cloudfunctions.net/sendNotification

To deploy the functions run

```
 npm run deploy
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {   
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^5.2.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.6.3"
  }
}
```

In the cloud function console you see them as separate functions.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for replying. Though what you are describing are Firebase functions, not Google Cloud Functions. Though similar, they are different things, and have different pricing structures for example. I was hoping for info on Google Cloud Function. Interesting that Firebase functions supports the multiple functions case so trivially...